# Arduino IDE 2.0 Beta doesn't start

Tags: arduino-ide-2

Yesterday i downloaded the new version of the IDE to take advantage of all the new features, but it just won't open. I tried installing it to different paths, different PC's, i deleted the package_index.json and the cache folder, but nothing. It stucks in the opening screen (see image below), any other ideas?[image]

Comment: Run it from the command line and see what errors you get? Maybe raise an issue on the github repo. It's beta software. Don't expect it to work, and if you want to use it, be prepared to debug it.

Comment: I've used v1.9 beta for 2 years; it has been stable and lots faster than 1.8 which was miserably slow to launch (macOS). 2.0 beta is described as "Experimental Software". Based on that, and your experience, I'd probably call it 2.0 alpha. But, yeah, if it's not a released version, somebody doesn't feel it's ready for prime time.

Comment: Arduino IDE 2.0 is a very slow start up. How long did you wait? I've since uninstalled it. I recall the start up splash screen being there at least a minute, which is longer than most people would normally wait for a splash screen.

Comment: FWIW, I'm running Beta 7 on a 2019 MBP w/ 16G and it's ready to go in about 7 sec, and that's w/ a hefty suite of Docker microservices running and RubyMine and DataGrip in the throes of a large project.

Answer (score 1):

I have a very slow internet connection and the Arduino IDE seems to depend a lot on it. When I launch it, I shut down internet and it opens in a breeze.

Comment: About the only time arduino-cli cares about your connection is when you're downloading new board definitions or libraries.

Comment: Perhaps you meant "and the Arduino **IDE 2.0** seems to depend a lot on it." ?

Comment: Noted. I guessed it was the cli the one blocking it from the notification pop-up you get when you start it offline.